# How to pass arrays from javascript to laravel controller using axios

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I'm handling my data with Vue 2. I'm Trying to call a controller method using axios, but I can't find a proper way to pass two arrays. I need to send them to my controller in order to make some database requests with them and get some data back.

I've manage to pass the arrays as strings as shown below, however, I would prefer not to transform the strings to arrays on my controller.

Could there be a way to do the same thing as I'm doing below but passing the arrays as arrays instead of strings or is this just not possible?

Axios call on Vue:

```
$rutas = ["01", "02"];
$tipos = ["01", "03", "04"];

var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("rutas", $rutas);
params.append("tipos", $tipos);

var request = {
  params: params
};
axios.get('/test/', request);
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('/test/', 'TestsController@getClientesPorRuta');
```

This is my controller's method:

```
public function getClientesPorRuta(Request $request) {
  $rutas = $request->input('rutas');
  $tipos = $request->input('tipos');
  
  // Code like this doesn't work
  $index = 0;
  $register = Ruta::where('CODIRUTA','=',$rutas[$index])->first();
}
```

Comment: you actually have done it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually you didn't have to convert that array to string to do that .. you can directly pass it ..

```
var request = {
  rutas: $rutas,
  tipos: $tipos,
};
axios.post('/test/', request);
```

use axios.post instead of axios.get .. since get method is using the url to pass the data .. and url cant contain array it is converting it to string like 1,2

also in your routes you should change the Route::get to Route::post

```
Route::post('/test/', 'TestsController@getClientesPorRuta');
```

then in your php `$request->rutas` is already set as `["01", "02"]`

Comment: My bad, the axios call converts the array to string. However I do have to convert it to an array if I want to use it as I want: `$register = Ruta::where('CODIRUTA','=',$rutas[$index])->first();`. My need to pass it as an array instead of a string remains. Offcourse, I could just convert it, but I want to know if it's possible.

Comment: since your rutas is an array in my answer .. you can retrieve a Ruta using `$register = Ruta::whereIn('CODIRUTA',$rutas)->first();`

Comment: If I run that code with an array `["01", "02"]` I will get the first one every time, I don't need to do the query with an array of ids ($rutas). I need to loop the $rutas and do the query individually so I can get a different "ruta" each time. Also, `$request->rutas` does not return an array `["01", "02"]`, it returns a string `"01,02"`. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: it is because you're converting it .. use `params.append("rutas", $rutas);` instead of `params.append("rutas", $strRutas);`

Comment: I'm working with `params.append("rutas", $rutas);` since you posted your answer. I'm not converting it.

Comment: if you pass an array why are you getting a string ?

Comment: I'm guessing because it's a get request. I honestly don't know but I am getting a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145166/discussion-between-demonyowh-and-somezombie).

Comment: chat.stackoverflow.com